# Question about Marginal Utility

Tags: microeconomics, utility

The following statement is given as true and I cannot make sense why. It is the only information given.

"The $MRS$ of flour in 1kg bags for flour in 2kg bags is negative and constant."

I thought working by $MU_{1kg}/MU_{2kg}$, but could not reach any conclusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is most likely an assumption in the background that utility is increasing in the amount of flour, independently of its packaging. Then you are willing to exchange two 1kg-bags of flour for one 2kg-bag of flour. Thus the MRS is -2 (or -0.5, depending on the direction of exchange).